# Is there any such shloka present in adi parva of Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request

> भवान् वा विधिवत् पाणिं गृह्णातु दुहितुर्मम। यस्य वा मन्यसे वार तस्य कृष्णामुपादिश।।

I got this shloka from an online website where it's mentioned that it's 50th shloka from 32nd adhyay of Adi parva.

I did check the Adi Parva's 32nd adhyay but it has only 25 shlokas.

Can anybody confirm if this Shloka is fake or which portion of vyasa Mahabharata does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Shloka is from Adi Parva but chapter and shloka numbers are different. It can be found in [187th chapter of Adi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01187.htm):

> 21 [दरुपद]
>     भवान वा विधिवत पाणिं गृह्णातु दुहितुर मम
>
> यस्य वा मन्यसे वीर तस्य कृष्णाम उपादिश

In [BORI edition](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh01_sa.html) also, it's in 187 (१८७) chapter.

---

English translation of this can be found [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01198.htm):

> Drupada said, 'If it pleaseth thee, take thou the hand of my daughter thyself with due rites. Or, give Krishna in marriage unto whomsoever of thy brothers thou likest.'

Comment: “अद्याहमनृणो भूत्वा भ्रातुर्भार्यापहारिणम्।
शांतिं लब्धास्मि परमां हत्वा सैरन्ध्रिकण्टकम्।।”

अपने बड़े भाई की पत्नी का अपहरण करने वाले , सैरंध्री के लिए कंटकरूप दुष्ट कीचक को मारकर आज मैं उऋण हो जाऊँगा और मुझे अत्यधिक शान्ति प्राप्त होगी।

Comment: Can you please tell me where is this Shaloka in virat parv as well? I didn't find it anywhere. Thank you so much for the above clarification.

Comment: @yogirajput You should post a new question for that one.